# Scrape Google News with lxml and python

Tags: python, dom, web-crawler, lxml, scraper

I'm trying to scrape Google News using python and lxml. Everything is going well but when I try to print each div data using a for loop everything mess up.
Here my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from lxml import html
from lxml import cssselect
from lxml import etree
import requests

proxies = {
    'http' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}

url = "https://www.google.it/search?hl=en&tbm=nws&as_occt=any&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:9/1/2014,cd_max:9/1/2014,sbd:1&as_nsrc=Daily%20Mail&start=0"

page = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies,headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
results = tree.xpath('//div[@class="_cnc"]')

for div in results:
    print(div)
```

I get this output:

```
<Element div at 0x7f4154df9470>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df94c8>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df9520>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df9578>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df95d0>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df9628>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df9680>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df96d8>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df9730>
<Element div at 0x7f4154df9788>
```

I would like to extract from each div -> title, href and snippet, with something like this:

```
....

for div in results:
    title = div.xpath('//a[@class="l _HId"]/text()')
    href = div.xpath('//a[@class="l _HId"]/@href')
    snippet = div.xpath('//div[@class="st"]/text()')
    #for example
    print(title)
....
```

When I try to print I get same multiple output:

```
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
['Pro-Russian rebels lower demands in peace talks', "'If I want to I can take Kiev in a fortnight': Putin's threat to Europe ", 'Showing a yen for business: PM Modi and Japanese premier Abe ', 'Modi visit draws pledges of support from Japan', 'The spectre of the Army rises again over Pakistan', 'Protesters briefly storm Pakistan state TV station', 'Anti-government protesters storm Pakistan state television station ', 'Austerity debate flares as Europe recovery fades', 'Inquiries begin into nude celebrity photo leaks', 'He tried to sell intimate pictures of Jennifer Lawrence in return for ']
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there - just *prepend the dots* to the inner XPath expressions to make them *specific to the context* of the current node:

```
for div in results:
    title = div.xpath('.//a[@class="l _HId"]/text()')
    href = div.xpath('.//a[@class="l _HId"]/@href')
    snippet = div.xpath('.//div[@class="st"]/text()')
    #for example
    print(title)
```